# Why is the spawned process message not received again by the sender?

Tags: elixir

I am trying to understand what is going on in this piece of Elixir code. We have two processes spawned, then the spawned process echo's the message back to the sender, but I only see one message in iex. Whats wrong?

```
defmodule TwoPs do
  # a simple echo function - take a pid to send message back to
  def echo(pid) do
    #wait till the spawned process receives a message, turn around and echo it back to the sender
    receive do
      msg ->
        IO.puts("Received #{msg}")
        send pid, {:ok, "Hello #{msg}"}
    end
  end

  #spawn's two processes and sends a message to both...expects an echo back from both spawned processes
  def create_ps() do
    #spawn the two processes
    p1 = spawn(TwoPs, :echo, [self])
    p2 = spawn(TwoPs, :echo, [self])

    #send a message to the first pid
    send p1, "World"

    #receive message back from spawned child 1
    receive do
      {:ok, msg} -> "#{msg}"
    end

    #send a message to the second pid
    send p2, "Bob"

    #receive message from the spawned child 2
    receive do
      {:ok, msg} -> "#{msg}"
    end

  end

end
```

The output in iex is always "Hello Bob"

```
iex(17)> TwoPs.create_ps
Received World
Received Bob
"Hello Bob"
```

Why don't we see "Hello World"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you see there is the return value of `TwoPs.create_ps/0` which in this case is the value returned by the second receive block. If you want to print both the received values, you should explicitly print them with `IO.puts/2`:

```
defmodule TwoPs do
  def echo(pid) do
    receive do
      msg ->
        IO.puts("Received #{msg}")
        send pid, {:ok, "Hello #{msg}"}
    end
  end

  def create_ps() do
    p1 = spawn(TwoPs, :echo, [self])
    p2 = spawn(TwoPs, :echo, [self])

    send p1, "World"
    receive do
      {:ok, msg} -> IO.puts "#{msg}"
    end

    send p2, "Bob"
    receive do
      {:ok, msg} -> IO.puts "#{msg}"
    end
  end
end
```

Test:

```
iex(1)> TwoPs.create_ps
Received World
Hello World
Received Bob
Hello Bob
:ok
```

Comment: Thank you. Amazingly fast response. Missed that completely. Dumb mistake on my part